# How to merge 2 different branches into git, without overwriting changes made by the first commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I have a master branch "Master" and I create 2 different branches off of it called "Branch-A" and "Branch-B" respectively. The branches are for two different features. When I'm done with Branch-A I merge it back into Master. All is well.

Now I finish Branch-B. I want to merge that into Master too but I know Branch-B doesn't contain the feature that I created in Branch-A which is now merged into Master. Will git see Branch-B as if the code has been changed back (as before Branch-A was merged into Master) and overwrite the changes from Branch-A in Master?

I hope I made this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. When you merge branch-b it will consider all changes coming from master (and branch-A, cause it's already part of master) and branch-B.

Comment: So it won't see the lack of code in Branch-B as a change, right?

Comment: Nope. What git does is, _roughly_, get the differences between the two tips of the branches you are merging _against_ their last common ancestor.... it actually doesn't work comparing the two tips against each other.